# Automatic excel script

Tags: microsoft-excel, script, automation

I have data of 400 patients, stored in 400 different excel files.
Each file contains 34 columns in a specific order, let's say A to Z.
The order is the same in each of these 400 files.

Now I need to a make a new excel document that contains the first column of each patient.
So I need all the first columns of my 400 different excel files, lined up next to each other in a new document. Preferebally in the form of a automatic script.

After that I want to do the exact same thing but for the second column, then the third and so on.

This is probably a problem that has already been solved. Otherwise could someone help me out?

Comment: What did you already try?

Answer (score 0):

Here someone has created a macro to put the contents of all open workbooks into one:

http://ask.metafilter.com/106144/Combining-a-ton-of-Excel-files-into-one-Excel-file

It could also be a good idea to import those into an Access or SQL database, especially since you have matching columns.